# parsing json C# / unity3d

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

Struggling to find a good solution to parse this data or similar structure in Unity using C#:

```
 {
 "levels":{
     "level1":{
         {0,1,0,0},
         {0,0,1,0},
         {0,2,0,0},
         {0,0,0,0},
     }
  }
}
```

I've tried the built in Unity C# class [JsonUtility](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html) and [Boomlagoon](https://bitbucket.org/boomlagoon/boomlagoon-json) plugin but havent been able to parse the data into a Levels 2 dimensional array of different Levels.

Any help would be appreicated.

Comment: I can do it with Regex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469765/how-to-deseralize-json-object-that-contains-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't find any solution as this is not a valid json.

The following would be a more appropriate solution:

```
{
    "levels": [{
        "name": "level1",
        "data": [
            [0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 2, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0]
        ]
    }]
 }
```

and the Csharp side would turn out to be :

```
public class Level
{
    public string name;
    public int[][]data; 
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Level[] levels;
}
```