# How do I pass a serialized multi dimensional array from C# to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I need to pass a matrix from the C# code behind to javascript, however at the moment when my matrix is passed to the view, it is converted into a single dimensional array. In other words, my multi dimensional array is flattened by the serialization.

C# code

```
List<leituras> listaleituras = new List<leituras>();
public object[,] arrayTemperatura = new object[5, 3];
public JavaScriptSerializer javaSerial = new JavaScriptSerializer();

foreach (var leitura in listaleituras)
{
    arrayTemperatura[i, 0] = leitura.Data.Month.ToString() + "/" + leitura.Data.Year.ToString();
    arrayTemperatura[i, 1] = leitura.Sensor_temperatura;
    arrayTemperatura[i, 2] = leitura.Sensor_temperatura;
    i++;
}
```

Output

[image]

expected output format

```
[  
  ["09/18",95,95],["10/18",257,257],["11/18",1368,1368],["12/18",1574,1574],
  ["01/19",2437,2437],["02/19",3105,3105],["1/3",2096,2096],["2/3",1098,1098],
  ["4/3",361,361],["6/3",1993,1993],["7/3",2744,2744],["8/3",2891,2891],
  ["9/3",1797,1797],["11/3",3027,3027],["12/3",2996,2996],["13/3",2766,2766],
  ["14/3",3067,3067],["15/3",3043,3043],["16/3",2374,2374]
]
```

How do I pass a serialized multi dimensional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`JSON.NET`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
string json_string = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arrayTemperatura);
```

it serializes multi-dimension arrays as you want.

then in javascript you can desrialize json using `JSON.parse`

```
var multidimentionArray = JSON.parse( json_string );
```

also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469765/how-to-deseralize-json-object-that-contains-multidimensional-array)

Comment: in javascript I had to add: var array = JSON.parse('<%=jsonString%>');
        console.log(array);

Answer (score 0):

Use a jagged array instead of a two-dimensional array.

First of all declare your array without intialising it:  `public object[][] arrayTemperatura;`

then do this after your `while` loop:

```
arrayTemperatura = new object[listaleituras.length][];

foreach (var leitura in listaleituras)
{
    arrayTemperatura[i] = new object[3];
    arrayTemperatura[i][0] = leitura.Data.Month.ToString() + "/"+ leitura.Data.Year.ToString();
    arrayTemperatura[i][1] = leitura.Sensor_temperatura;
    arrayTemperatura[i][2] = leitura.Sensor_temperatura;
    i++;
}
```

Alternatively you could use the [Json.NET serializer](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) instead of the `JavaScriptSerializer` - I have created an example to show that it just behaves the way you'd expect in your question: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2QBP7J

Comment: As a side note, assuming that leitura.Data is a DateTime, your formatted date could be done using `arrayTemperatura[i][0] = leitura.Data.ToString("M/y");`