# How to save complex classes in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save

I have a class called Container. This class contains a 2D array with a not consistent size. The array contains a different class called Slot. That class also contains a few parameters:

```
public Container Container { get; private set; }
public Vector2 Position { get; private set; }
public Item Item { get; private set; }

public int Capacity { get; private set; }
public int Count { get; private set; }

public bool IsEquipped { get; private set; }

public SlotUI SlotUI { get; private set; }
```

On of these parameters is a own class aswell. Luckily this class doesn't needs to be saved.
**Is there an easy way to store it with e.g. PlayerPrefs or a json data?**

In a older project of mine I stored the content of an 2D array by looping every element through and
convertet them into json with JsonUtility.ToJson(). After that I putted them together in a long text document and saved that.

But that seems to be much to complex.

Comment: Actually, the way you described for your old project is one of the easiest possible :D

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html

Comment: Check out [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469765/how-to-deseralize-json-object-that-contains-multidimensional-array)

You may try to use [Newtonsoft JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) . Its perfectly working in Unity